# Adding background textures to a three js demo file

Tags: three.js, background-image, addition, edit, multiple-instances

Being new to three.js I like to learn by example. That being said I found the earth demo html. I've successfully changed the earth texture. Now I want to change the earth demo background to an image or create at larger rectangle doubleside that surrounds the sphere while maintaining the 3d aspect. Can I initiate multiple scenes and objects by editing the demo and inserting code into the existing demo file? Three's demo files are commented which helped me figure out some edits but any additions I've added causes the demo to malfunction. I'm sure it's code placement and syntax errors on my part! My objectives are add counter clockwise rotating clouds to the"earth". Encircle the earth with a crystal ball, and create a background in place of the white container. any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated here's the code:

```
<style>
        body {
            color: #000000;
            font-family:Monospace;
            font-size:13px;
            text-align:center;

            background-color: #b49ebb;
            background-image: url("textures/rainier.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover; 
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #info {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px; width: 100%;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        a {

            color: #0080ff;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="info"><a href="http://therionsolutions.byethost15.com" target="_blank">Therion Solutions</a>The Oasis</div>

    <script src="../build/three.js"></script>

    <script src="js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>

    <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var container, stats;
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var group;
        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;



        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
            camera.position.z = 500;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            group = new THREE.Group();
            scene.add( group );



            // earth

            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            loader.load( 'textures/land_ocean_ice_cloud_2048o.jpg', function ( texture ) {

                var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200, 20, 20 );

                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 } );
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                group.add( mesh );

            } );


            //Background


            // shadow

            var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
            canvas.width = 128;
            canvas.height = 128;

            var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
            var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(
                canvas.width / 2,
                canvas.height / 2,
                0,
                canvas.width / 2,
                canvas.height / 2,
                canvas.width / 2
            );
            gradient.addColorStop( 0.1, 'rgba(210,210,210,1)' );
            gradient.addColorStop( 1, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)' );

            context.fillStyle = gradient;
            context.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

            var texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture( canvas );

            var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 300, 300, 3, 3 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 } );

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            mesh.position.y = - 250;
            mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
            group.add( mesh );

            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


            stats = new Stats();
            container.appendChild( stats.dom );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            render();
            stats.update();

        }

        function render() {

            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            group.rotation.y -= 0.005;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }


    </script>
```

PS I always credit the author when I adapt scripts for my use

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Can I initiate multiple scenes and objects by editing the demo and inserting code into the existing demo file? I've tried that with little success. Some edits have worked where others haven't. Changing the sphere container background has't work via css, New render instance of WebGL, or SetClearColor